# How to center images in a stack exchange post

Tags: horizontal-alignment, center, figure-placement

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832197/a-cantor-like-metric-space-which-is-not-path-connected) Mathematics Stack exchange post of mine, I have included an image. I have tried relentlessly to center the image, but none of the usual methods that work in a LaTeX script work, `\centering` does not work. `\begin{center}` does not work. I even tried manually creating horizontal space using `\hspace`. This too, does not work. I consulted the mathjax [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and it does not seem to adress the issue.

Is this just one of those things we aren't meant to do, or can someone alleviate my suffering?

Comment: that is a question about stackexchange markdown so unrelated to latex, sorry.

Comment: as it is a question about the site not about tex it should be asked on the network meta, but it is already asked there, eg https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't delete the question anymore, since it has an answer now. Even though the question was not related to latex, the solution was, so I don't think it is as misplaced as you suggested

Comment: math.stackexchange (but not this site) uses mathjax emulation of some parts of latex math syntax but it does not use tex at all and does not implement non math features such as centering, the question in certainly off topic here but glad you found something that works for you, which is one of the answers in the linked meta question I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hspace` definitely work here:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

```
$\hspace{3cm}$![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw7Sw.png)
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't using it correctly